# Has Canon released any point and shoot cameras without optical low-pass filters?

Tags: canon, sensor, point-and-shoot, anti-aliasing

Do either the Canon PowerShot SD880 IS or the S100 have anti-aliasing filters?
If so, has Canon announced any P&S model(s) without OLPFs?

Answer (score 1):

Not as of 2013.

Canon is a bit late to the game. Nikon, Olympus, Pentax, and Fuji for example make various cameras without optical low-pass filters.

It is quite a new development for a variety of reasons, most of which have been covered in existing questions/answers on this site. Take a look at:

- [Why only recently are digital cameras being sold without low-pass filters?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35587/why-only-recently-are-digital-cameras-being-sold-without-low-pass-filters)
- [Why is a physical anti-aliasing filter still needed on modern DSLRs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34407/why-is-a-physical-anti-aliasing-filter-still-needed-on-modern-dslrs)
- [What is the difference between the newly launched Nikon D800 and D800E?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20131/what-is-the-difference-between-the-newly-launched-nikon-d800-and-d800e)